# Git - how to include only certain files and dirs from the whole working tree?

Tags: git

I am developing an extension for magento. There is a lot of files in working dir, but I need to include in git only those I added in extension. How can I define in .gitignore rules for this case?

I tried this - **.gitignore**:

```
*
!/app/etc/modules/Some_Ext.xml
!/app/code/local/Some/Ext/
!/app/designer/...
... - etc.
```

But when I try **git status** it shows only **.gitignore** itself.

When I replace asterisk with certain dirs it doesn't change anything. What is a proper way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Because you have `...` in your example, I can't be sure but it may be that you need to explicitly unignore directories that contain files that you don't wish to ignore. e.g. `!/app/`.

Comment: I tried to change the first line to `/*` and it worked. But I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: @CharlesBailey - '...' means similar list of files and subdirs. 'app' contains stuff I do not need, if I add '!/app/' - I shall have to filter it again, shall not I? And how to avoid it? Or what is the principle of ignoring dirs and its content?

Comment: @dyng - not for me :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

There is an easier solution:

```
*
!*/
!/app/etc/modules/Some_Ext.xml
!/app/code/local/Some/Ext/
!/app/designer/...
... - etc.
```

The second line will include all directories again then following patterns can take effect.

---

Well, have explored the source code, I found the 'gitignore' mechanism is in some degree really tricky.

Some points summarized as below:

1. Be careful to ignore a directory. Git searches untracked files in a recursive way, ignoring directory will cause git skip that directory and automatically ignores all files / subdirectories under that, even you have a "not"-pattern. So

   ```
   /app
   !/app/code/index.php
   ```

   won't save `index.php`, it will be ignored together with `/app`.
2. Do your best, use `*.xml/txt/conf/etc...` instead. And it is a good idea that never use standalone `*` because it will ignore any directories, which may be not what you want.
3. There is no **priority** but **order**. For a directory or file, git matches the path against to `.gitignore` line by line and use the **last** matched pattern. If the last matched pattern has a leading `!`, git will include the file/directory, otherwise will ignore it.

   So

   ```
   *.xml
   !/app/etcmodules/Some_Ext.xml
   ```

   will reserve the `Some_Ext.xml` but

   ```
   !/app/etcmodules/Some_Ext.xml
   *.xml
   ```

   will filter it out.
4. Update git to version 1.8.2 may help. In 1.8.2, they add a command `git check-ignore` for debugging your `.gitignore` config.

---

I think a workflow of `git add -A` can explain more.

Suppose there is a repository like this.

```
.
├── a.conf
├── b
│   └── b.conf
└── c
    └── c1
        └── c2
            └── c.conf
```

And in `.gitignore` it is

```
*.conf
b/
!b/b.conf
!c/c1/c2/c.conf
```

When I run `git add -A`, git will

1. scan the working directory, find there is one regular file `a.conf` and two directories `b` and `c`.
2. notice that file `a.conf` matches `*.conf` in `.gitignore`, then ignore it.
3. `b` is a directory but is excluded by pattern `b/` in `.gitignore`, stop recursing into `b`.
4. because `b` is excluded, `b/b.conf` has never been scanned. ( Although he is unexcluded in the third line of `.gitignore` )
5. `c` is a directory and seems not bad, include it and continue to recursing into it.
6. `c/c1/c2/c.conf` matches two patterns, but the last one determines the fate. Because the last matched pattern `!c/c1/c2/c.conf` has a leading `!`, `c/c1/c2/c.conf` will survive.

Here is the result of `git add -A` at my machine (Mac with git of version 1.8.2)

```
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   .gitignore
#       new file:   c/c1/c2/c.conf
```

Comment: Thanks. That starts to make sense for me. Still not quite clear why `!` is ignored if it has to have higher priority.

Comment: Thanks @dyng ! Now I understand it. If I set ignore for `app/` and then `!app/code/file.php` it will ignore `app/code/` as it does not match 'not' pattern and will never look into it to find some other 'not' pattern. If I am right, it doesn't see patterns as dirs/files, just strings to match path strings of the project.

Comment: @Taras Yes, it matches the path strings. More exactly, `app/code/` is ignored because `app/` is ignored, there is no way to save a file if his parent directory is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You may try replacing `!/app/` by `!app/`.